# ConTeXt: Repeat second-level registers within index

Tags: context, indexing

## Background

In ConTeXt, a multi-level index can be created using:

```
\index{level1+level2}text
```

If the value for `level2` matches the previous index value of `level2`, then the text for `level2` is not repeated.

## Problem

I would like for the `level2` to be repeated as per the expected outcome shown below:

[image: Repeated Section Title]

In the image, `SECTION A` is repeated (identified in red), but only because in the code snippet the middle "`SECTION A`" actually contains an extra space (i.e., "`SECTION A` ").

When the exact same section title is actually repeated (identified in orange), the section title is hidden.

## Code

To illustrate the problem:

```
\define[1]\AnimalName{%
  \expanded{\index{#1+\namedstructurevariable{section}{title}}{#1}}%
}

\define[1]\AnimalQuant{#1}
\define[1]\AnimalGroup{#1}
\define[3]\Animal{
  \startitem
    \AnimalQuant{#1} \AnimalGroup{#2} \AnimalName{#3}
  \stopitem
}

\setupregister[index][
  textstyle=\em,
  style=\tfa\bold,
  balance=no,
  command=\Word,
]

\starttext
  \placeindex[compress=yes]
  \startchapter[title={Chapter 1}]
    \startsection[title={Section A}]
      \Animal{6}{rookery}{albatross}
      \Animal{12}{wisdom}{wombat}
      \Animal{10}{plague}{locusts}
      \Animal{11}{lounge}{lizard}
      \Animal{6}{pride}{lion}
      \startitem
        5 array \index{hedgehog+SECTION A}hedgehog
      \stopitem
      \startitem
        7 army \index{herring+SECTION A }herring
      \stopitem
      \startitem
        100 bloat \index{hippopotamuses+SECTION A}hippopotamuses
      \stopitem
    \stopsection
  \stopchapter
\stoptext
```

Change:

```
7 army \index{herring+SECTION A }herring
```

to (by removing the extra space after `SECTION A` ):

```
7 army \index{herring+SECTION A}herring
```

After making `SECTION A` exactly the same, the index is collapsed (hidden/removed):

[image: Missing Level 2]

## Question

How do you prevent ConTeXt from collapsing duplicate level 2 index titles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with ConTeXt. To fix it:

1. Edit `context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/strc-reg.lua/strc-reg.lua`.
2. Change from line 695:

   ```
       for i=1,4 do -- max 4
           if list[i] then
               e[i] = list[i][1]
           end
           if e[i] ~= done[i] then
               if e[i] and e[i] ~= "" then
                   done[i] = e[i]
                   for j=i+1,4 do done[j] = false end

                   if n == i then
                       context.stopregisterentries()
                       context.startregisterentries(n)
                   else
                       while n > i do
                           n = n - 1
                           context.stopregisterentries()
                       end
                       while n < i do
                           n = n + 1
                           context.startregisterentries(n)
                       end
                   end
                   local internal  = entry.references.internal or 0
                   local seeparent = entry.references.seeparent or ""
                   local processor = entry.processors and entry.processors[1] or ""
                   if metadata then
                       context.registerentry(processor,internal,seeparent,function() helpers.title(e[i],metadata) end)
                   else -- ?
                       context.registerentry(processor,internal,seeindex,e[i])
                   end
               else
                   done[i] = false
                   for j=i,4 do done[j] = false end
               end
           end
       end
   ```

Save the file then recompile using `context --make`.

Comment: Or just download the new beta (in a day or so).